# SQL: Can we select the content in one column as the new columns in the new table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example:
input:

```
company    amount     vendor    ID(ai)
  A1        100         B1        1
  A2        150         B1        2
  A3        200         B2        3
  A1        100         B3        4
```

output:

```
vendor   A1      A2      A3     Total
  B1     100     150     NULL   250
  B2     NULL    NULL    200    200
  B3     100     NULL    NULL   100
```

Comment: you are looking for pivot tables. Plenty of questions about this here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select vendor,
       sum(case when company = 'A1' then amount end) as a1,
       sum(case when company = 'A2' then amount end) as a2,
       sum(case when company = 'A3' then amount end) as a3,
       sum(amount) as total
from t
group by vendor;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is a perfect solution!